# why vim script change inside visual area not work?

Tags: vim, script

Say a webpage like this:

```
...
<div class="block">
    <p>...</p>
    <p>...</p>
</div>
<p>...</p>
...
```

I tried to add class="cls" to <p>s inside <div class="block">, so I did:

```
while search('div class="block"','W') > 0
    normal vat    
    '<,'>s@<p>@<p class="cls">@gec
endw
```

but this wouldn't work as expected: those <p>s outside <div class="block"> got changed too. In command window these lines totally work, why not putting together?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After the `normal vat`, the visual selection still persists, and the `'<,'>` marks still refer to the previous one. You need to end visual mode, like this:

```
:execute "normal! vat\<Esc>"
```

PS: [You should use `:noremap`](http://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/chapters/05.html); it makes the mapping immune to remapping and recursion.